# SAS: Do-loop and Array

Tags: arrays, loops, sas

I have a data set of person records, organized into households.

- Serial: Household number, members of the same household have the same serial
- Persons: number of persons in this household
- Pernum: an unique number assigned to each person within each household
- MOMLOC: shows who (by pernum) this person's mother is within the household, 0 indicates that there is no mother of this person in the household
- POPLOC: same for each person's father
- SPLOC: same for each person's spouse
- RELATE: person's relationship with the household head, 1=head, 2=spouse, 3=child, 4=other

The goal is to create a new variable, called NCH, if a person is 65 years or older, and 
1 means lives with son(s)
2 means lives with daughter(s)
3 means lives with both son(s) and daughter(s)
. means does not live with child

I think an array with do loop should be able to accomplish this, but I have very little experience doing this in SAS. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: 1. It seems to be a perfect case for PROC SQL, not DATA step. 2. How on Earth one should determine the sex of the child from the data you described?

Comment: This is too broad of a question.  Try to solve it yourself, and ask if you have a question about some aspect of it.  Stack Overflow is not a "Do your work for you" site.

Comment: Oops sorry, sex and age are also included for each person. Joe, well, I guess the specific question is, how do you tell SAS to do an action repeatedly, by household serial while matching one's MOMLOC or POPLOC to the PERNUM of the mom or dad in the household. It's probably an intro question I guess, but obviously I posted it here because I have no one to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with two solutions, one using proc sql and one using the data step. Here is the proc sql solution:

```
proc sql;
    create table new as 
    select *, 
        case when 'M' in (select b.sex from people as b where a.serial=b.serial 
            and (a.pernum = b.momloc or a.pernum = b.poploc)) 
            then 1 else 0 end as son,
        case when 'F' in (select c.sex from people as c where a.serial=c.serial 
            and (a.pernum = c.momloc or a.pernum = c.poploc))
            then 1 else 0 end as daughter,
        case when calculated son = 1 and calculated daughter = 0 then 1
            when calculated son = 0 and calculated daughter = 1 then 2
            when calculated son = 1 and calculated daughter = 1 then 3
            else .
            end as nch
    from people as a
    where age >= 65;
quit;
```

The "case" expression is like "if then" in regular SAS. The main query is against the table people, which is given an "alias" of a. The select statements in parentheses are called sub-queries. They query the table people with an alias of b and c. They sub-queries are to check weather there exists a male (or female) where serial in a equals serial in b (or c), and pernum in a equals momloc or poploc in b (or c).

Here is the data step solution:

```
data test;
    set people;
    where age >= 65;
    son = 0;
    daughter = 0;
    do i = 1 to nobs;
        set people (keep=serial momloc poploc sex age 
            rename=(serial=serial1 momloc=momloc1 poploc=poploc1 sex=sex1 age=age1)) 
            point=i nobs=nobs;
        if sex1 = 'M' and serial=serial1 and (pernum = momloc1 or pernum = poploc1) 
            then son = 1;
        if sex1 = 'F' and serial=serial1 and (pernum = momloc1 or pernum = poploc1) 
            then daughter = 1;
    end;
    if son = 1 and daughter = 0 then nch = 1;
    else if son = 0 and daughter = 1 then nch = 2;
    else if son = 1 and daughter = 1 then nch = 3;
    else nch = .;
    drop serial1 momloc1 poploc1 sex1 age1 son daughter;
run;
```

Here the data step is cycling through the set "people" one record at a time, and for each record it cycles through every record the same data set "people". "Nobs" is the number of observations in "people", and "point" is the number corresponding to each record.

Comment: It's taking a very very long time to run (few hours) because the dataset is so large, but I subsetted it and tried the code and it worked out perfectly. Thank you so much!